# Current ES6 module syntax

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

(Followup to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27488556/1048572))

Please can someone confirm that the following syntax is still valid in ES6?

```
module "javascripts/bar" {
    export function Bar() {}
}
```

I am thinking about the scenario where I use concatenation. Yes I know HTTP2 will make concatenation moot, but I would like to concatenate my modules today.

If this is not valid, how should I construct my modules so that they remain valid in the same file?

Comment: It cannot be parsed by esprima, or transpiled by 6to5, so probably not.

Comment: Similarly, `module` is not on the latest [list of keywords](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-keywords). (It'd be nice if the spec were actually readable, though, eh? I thought the ES5 spec was bad, but it's got nothing on the ES6 spec...)

Comment: @Felix is there a forum where I can ask detailed ES6 questions other than S/O?

Comment: Maybe https://esdiscuss.org/ .

Comment: I'd also suggest to separate modules into files and just have a build step that compiles them together.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: (my thoughts as well)

Comment: @Felix that is exactly what I intend to do. My question then becomes: what is the required transformation? Do I have to create an IIFE? If so, I dont think I'll bother with modules in the first place, since I am already using IIFEs for modularisation.

Comment: I guess it depends on where you want to use the code eventually. I don't think any environment supports ES6 modules, so you'd have to convert them to something else. Have a look at 6to5 which transpiles ES6 modules to either CJS, AMD or what not: https://6to5.org/modules.html

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's pretty understandable that it's not a keyword. What do you think would happen to code that has `var module = x;` in ES5 if it was a keyword? Still [modules are very much there](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-modules) in ES6. The syntax is not current though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Right. The question was whether the above is (still) valid, and I was suggesting that it probably wasn't, as it would require `module` to be a keyword. Extremely hard to introduce new keywords into an existing language, regardless of how contextually-sensitive you make it. (`export`, on the other hand, which is used with ES6 modules, has been on the "future reserved words" list basically forever.)

Comment: Ah, in that case the above is not valid. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the old module syntax that was removed. The above is no longer valid since Rev28 of the ES6 draft. Do not use this syntax any more it is not valid ES6. ([relevant esdiscuss with it being removed](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/a-new-es6-draft-rev28)) ([esdiscuss coming to the conclusion to remove it](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/module-naming-and-declarations))

ES6 has a module-per-file module. If a file is imported using `import` it will be treated as a module.

Update: I just noticed [that Alex has written about it](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) that is probably a good read on the subject. His [links are wrong](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2014-09/sept-25.md#conclusionresolution-1) though.